# Is IAppBuilder.UseWelcomePage the correct middleware to use for showing a page once?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

I am using OWIN and want to show a disclaimer message every time the application is loaded. I can't rely on showing this message in Home/Index, because the user might bookmark some other part of the application and end up bypassing it.

I tried doing the following in my startup class, but that doesn't seems like it did anything.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
    Wtrealm = Realm,
    MetadataAddress = AdfsMetadata
});
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
app.UseWelcomePage(@"/Account/Disclaimer"); // <-- this is the page I want to show
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the welcome page is a fixed page. It doesn't look like you can set the content of that page.

You should review other questions on SO relating to MVC Web API default routes, static files, or default files.